# Null Reference Exception in Switch Case

Tags: unity, c#

I'm getting an annoying NullReferenceException error. Can anyone help? This is the function, and below you can see how it is called:

Error message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> BotController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/BotController.cs:64)

```
void Start()
{   
    InvokeRepeating("RandomMove", 0f, waitTime);
}
```

function:

```
    void RandomMove()
    {
        float behaviour = Random.Range(0,3);
        switch(behaviour)
        {
            //0: move left, 1: stop, 2: move right //
            case 0: rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            movingRight = false;
            break;
            case 1: rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
            break;
            case 2: rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            movingRight = true;
            break;
        }
        return;
    }
```

the console shows the error on this line:

```
 case 0: rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
```

Edit: I've just changed the function to this:

```
void RandomMove()
    {
        float behaviour = Random.Range(0,3);
        switch(behaviour)
        {
            //0: move left, 1: stop, 2: move right //
            case 0: movingRight = false;
            break;
            case 1: rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
            break;
            case 2: movingRight = true;
            break;
        }
        return;
    }
```

and I've put an initial speed inside the Start() function like this:

```
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
```

Now it shows the error exactly on this line. I think something's up with either Rigidbody or the vectors. I'm using the same rigidbody inside the same script with no issues.

Comment: the error should tell you the line, from there you should be able to deduct what it is causing it. Always good to post the exact error message as well. PROBABLY you want int for behaviour and not float

Comment: @Zibelas I edited the thread, can you look at it again?

Comment: Your rb variable is null. That's the only reference variable on these lines, so it's the only one that can possibly throw a null reference exception. If you'd like help fixing this, you'll need to show us a Minimal Complete Verifiable example, including where you're assigning `rb` and any and all code that runs between then and the error.

Comment: @DMGregory I just referenced it as "Rigidbody2D rb;" at up top of the script. I used "rb" in many places in the same script without any issue.

Comment: That's where you declare it. By the rules of C#, it will be initialized with a value of `null`. Where do you assign a non-null value to that variable?

Comment: if it is a private Rigidbody, you need to grab it with GetComponent, if it is public, you can assign it in the editor. Either is missing, which means it is null

Comment: Your code is not showing any error in the editor since the editor does not know at that time it is null, so it could technically work. Practically you want to use something that you forgot to actually assign, therefore the error. It is not working on any line in the script, you get the error on the line that is first called

Comment: I just changed the rb to public Rigidbody 2D, now I can test the game but now my function does not work. I've even set an initial velocity to the rigidbody but something is off. This seems like it gave birth to a whole different problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you drag your rigidbody from your gameobject in the editor in the script? and if you have another problem with something else, you can always open a question, describe your problem and you may get help if someone can. Just be sure to identify WHAT is not working, or how it SHOULD work, and what you DID. And include the full code example.